# How to provide information for library code client when there are only concepts?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

Lets consider following situation, I'm writing library and instead of runtime polymorphism which comes with cost, but have clear and visible interface with all declarations, I choose generic programming instead. Example code:

```
template<class T>
concept has_method1 = requires(T o){{ o.method1(int()) -> std::same_as<int>; }};

template<class T>
concept has_method2 = requires(T o){{ o.method2(); }};

template<class T>
concept has_any_method = has_method1<T> || has_method2<T>;

template<class T>
requires has_any_method<T>
void example(T o);
```

And that's it, no more information is visible to the user of this library code, also the `requires` statement is hidden in IDE signature lookup (clangd), so clients have to manually walk through to find such information and the concepts could be separated/shattered in another header file/s, also could be way more complicated then this example, hard to see intent. As a client of such library I would be mad, as the documentation is the only way to tell without having to walk through all library code, even through I have more freedom like the methods can have more parameters, or the class can have both methods at the same time, or different return type. These freedoms are not possible to encode in interface which would be used in runtime polymorphism, so providing dummy interface class with virtual methods which is not really used anywhere just to provide declarations is not ideal either.

There are a lot benefits of this "template-concept-prototyping", like no cost (due to compile-time nature), more freedom and less code, I would like to have these in future codes, but without interfaces it isn't practical to use so I kinda see it as a code smell right now.

Is there any way to provide interface/prototype information within code in clean compact and uniform way ?

I have seen something similar to this which was called "[rubber-types](http://aherrmann.github.io/programming/2014/10/19/type-erasure-with-merged-concepts/)", but it is about type-erasure, providing united interface to incompatible objects, but it kinda solves this issue. Unfortunately there is runtime cost and a lot code to write so it kinda counters the benefits.

Comment: There are cleaner ways to write it if you don't compose concepts with `||`. I fail to see how that concept would be easy to use, because you'd need to `if constexpr` in the function definition, in which case it would be cleaner to express as two function template overloads constrained on `has_method1` and `has_method2`.

Comment: Side note don't forget to put everything in a namespace of your own

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have come to this while trying to implement logger with severity specification, main goal was to have zero runtime cost in case the severity level is not in use, and yes it uses `if constexpr` in function definition, overloads are not good for this case. I know that could be done the old way like `#ifdef _DEBUG` but that have its own dis/advantages.

Comment: How about a doc comment before the method showing examples of what T should be? I'd read such a comment.

Comment: @battlmonstr straight to the point, actually doc comments are really good solution, can't believe I didn't think of that. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A poor-man's approach would be to add a doc comment in front of `void example(T o);` showing examples of what T should be:

```cpp
/**

T interface is either:

struct T {
    void method1();
}

or:

struct T {
    int method2(int arg);
}

 */
template<class T>
requires has_any_method<T>
void example(T o);
```